# Typedef enum setting and accessing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, enums, typedef

I have this before the interface declaration in my `MainView.h` header.

```
typedef enum { UNKNOWN, CLEAR, NIGHT_CLEAR, CLOUDY, NIGHT_CLOUDY } Weather;
```

Then I declared it like this:

```
Weather weather;
```

Then made an accessor:

```
@property Weather weather;
```

And synthesized it.

**My question is, how can I use this in a different class without it crashing?**   I've imported the header for MainView. 
I tried to use it like this:

```
MainView* myView = (MainView*)self.view;

[myView setWeather: CLEAR];
```

It doesn't throw me any errors in Xcode, but it crashes when the code is run, saying:

```
-[UIView setWeather:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance *blah*
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Checking Weather, which looks like a type here, prolly wont work. Need to check the instance?

Comment: Thanks for replying.  How would check the instance?

Comment: In C,  you would create a variable of the type Weather like so:
Weather todaysWeather;   - todaysWeather is the variable/ the instance of Weather and would be checked thus:  if (todaysWeather == Weather.CLEAR) ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Weather' is a type not a variable.

So, you want something like this:

```
Weather theWeather = [mainView weather];
if (theWeather == CLEAR)
{
<do something>
}
```

Where MainView has ivar:

```
 Weather weather;
```

Comment: That was the correct way to do it, but when declaring it I didn't do it the way you wrote (although I'm sure it would work), but I instead put it in my interface and then made it a property.  Then I could use it as a variable.

Comment: How would I access the `weather` variable outside of my class, though?

Comment: Typically, I define enums and #defines in a .h file that is then included in all my other .h files. Of course there are exceptions. That said, your property 'weather' should be accessible via getter/setter from anywhere that has access to an instance of your class. That said, the capitalization of 'MainView' in your code example causes me concern; that is the name of your class. An instance of MainView should be called something else, like mainView. Further, there is a good chance that 'weather' should be stored somewhere other than MainView, but that's neither here nor there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the `*` in `Weather* weather`. `weather` has to be an integer, not a pointer.

Comment: That was precisely the problem in my declaration.